# Error in QTCreator 4.14.1 (Python): No documents matching "ui_form.h" could be found

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyqt5, qt-creator

I am trying to create a GUI in QTCreator using Python but whenever I try to edit the code on a button I get the following error.

[image: Editing code on Button]

[image: Selecting the slot I want to edit]

[image: Error when selecting onClicked]

I have tried rebuilding the project multiple times and I am still getting the same error.

Comment: There's an old bug here that looks similar: [QTCREATORBUG-9683](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-9683). Maybe that regression has reappeared in whatever version you're currently using.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues using c++, and I just added a slot in the header file and corresponding function in cpp file.

For my application, it was about the double spin box in a second window. I just followed the naming convention that qtcreator made for another example, and it worked.

in header file:

```
private slots:
void on_doubleSpinBox_MaxDepth_valueChanged(double arg1);
```

in cpp file:

```
void ProjectionsWindow::on_doubleSpinBox_MaxDepth_valueChanged(double arg1) {
//do something}
```

I'm not sure how it should be written in python, but maybe try similar method?

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue. if there is a .pro file check in there to see if the form.h is in the same format as well as in your form.cpp   I had to delete and re-add them and do a rebuild all and it worked I hope it works for you as well.